# How to use "executeScript" method of inAppBrowser plugin in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I have this code in a click event

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser('http://example.com/test', '_self');
browser.executeScript({code: "(function() { alert(123); })()"});
```

When i click the button, inAppBrowser opens the page, but the script doesn't run.
I closed the browser and then clicked the button again, now the script does run.

Why it's not running for the first time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add executeScript inside a InAppBrowser.addEventListener (loadstart, loadstop, loaderror) then it will run at the first time. I am using ionic 1 but I guess it will also work in ionic 2. I added a sample code below. (This is how it look like in ionic 1).

```
  browser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(){
            browser.executeScript({code: "(function() { alert(123); })()"});
        })
```

Comment: When I try to addEventListener it tells me that "Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type 'InAppBrowser'. What's going on here?

Comment: did you installe the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)?

Comment: I did and that method is not a part of the Ionic wrapped version. I gained access to it by using the regular cordova version.

Comment: @rashadb With the Ionic wrapper, use `on` instead of `addEventListener`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560757/276648

Answer (score 4):

It's not working in this way anymore. Try it!

```
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(() => {
  browser.executeScript({code: 'your_code'})
});
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code. This was working for me.

```
   var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.test.com/", '_blank');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
                ref.executeScript({
                    code: '//put the script you want to run here'
                });
            })
```

Please make sure that _blank is given and not _system. _system will open the native browser (eg chrome)

Comment: dear. team, we want to parse cookies to browser and we are developing the application ionic 3 based. please help us

Comment: we tried this.inAppBrowserInstance = this.inAppBrowser.create(URL, '_blank');    
this.inAppBrowserInstance.on('beforeload')
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.inAppBrowserInstance.executeScript({ code: `document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=cookievalue"` }).then().   but not working

Answer (score 0):

@Andrews' answer worked perfectly for me. Here is my full code for an Ionic 3 app using @ionic-native/themeable-browser:

```
let options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
        statusbar: { color: '#1976d2ff' },
        toolbar: { height: 44, color: '#1976d2ff' },
        closeButton: { align: 'right', event: 'closed', wwwImage: '/assets/images/icons/close-empty.png', wwwImagePressed: '/assets/images/icons/close-outline.png', wwwImageDensity: 3 },
        usewkwebview: 'yes',
        disallowoverscroll: 'yes',
        allowInlineMediaPlayback: 'yes',
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: 'no'
    },
    browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = self.iab.create(url, '_blank', options);
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(() => {
        browser.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.classList.add("cordova-ios");' });
    });
}
```

This way I can style iOS in Cordova explicitly via `body.cordova-ios` class inheritance

Answer (score 0):

@RezaT1994 Changing '_self' to '_blank' fixed this problem for me.

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser('http://example.com/test', '_blank');
browser.executeScript({code: "(function() { alert(123); })()"});
```

Answer (score 0):

On recent development, I have noticed that no event listener is working on the latest ionic project. However, without adding any event listener you can add javascript inside your InAppBrowser by directly calling
InAppBrowser.executeScript() function.